# WP ajax call Please wait while your request is being verified

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am trying to run ajax call in Wordpress website.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_plugin_check_r', 'my_plugin_check_r');

function my_plugin_check_r() {

    if(isset($_POST['token'])){

        $token = trim($_POST['token']);

        $response = ... do something

        echo json_encode($response);
        wp_die();

    }else{

        echo json_encode(false);
        wp_die();
    }
}

var postData = [
        {name: 'action', value: 'my_plugin_check_r'},
        {name: 'token', value: v},
    ];

    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_url,
        type: 'post',
        data: postData,
        dataType: 'json',   
    }).done(function(r){

        var response = JSON.parse(r)

   }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        
      
    });
```

However response looks like this, which is not coming from my code and I dont understand what is this?

```
                  <!doctype html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
            <title>One moment, please...</title>
            <style>
            body {
                background: #F6F7F8;
                color: #303131;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                margin-top: 45vh;
                text-align: center;
            }
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            <h1>Please wait while your request is being verified...</h1>
            <form id="wsidchk-form" style="display:none;" action="/z0f76a1d14fd21a8fb5fd0d03e0fdc3d3cedae52f" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" id="wsidchk" name="wsidchk"/>
            </form>
            <script>
            (function(){
                var west=+((+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+![])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![])),
                    east=+((+!+[]+!![])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+![]+[])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])),
                    x=function(){try{return !!window.addEventListener;}catch(e){return !!0;} },
                    y=function(y,z){x() ? document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",y,z) : document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",y);};
                y(function(){
                    document.getElementById('wsidchk').value = west + east;
                    document.getElementById('wsidchk-form').submit();
                }, false);
            })();
            </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

When I look in network panel under Headers Status code is 200 OK.

Response headers are:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:
        true
        Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
        https://www.....
        Age:
        0
        Cache-Control:
        no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, no-store, private
        Content-Encoding:
        gzip
        Content-Length:
        657
        Content-Type:
        text/html; charset=UTF-8
        Date:
        Mon, 08 Jan 2024 18:40:59 GMT
        Expires:
        Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
        Pragma:
        no-cache
        Referrer-Policy:
        strict-origin-when-cross-origin
        Server:
        Apache
        Vary:
        Accept-Encoding
        Via:
        1.1 webcache1 (Varnish/trunk)
        X-Content-Type-Options:
        nosniff
        X-Frame-Options:
        SAMEORIGIN
        X-Powered-By:
        PHP/8.1.27
        X-Robots-Tag:
        noindex
        X-Varnish:
        1639091928
```